# ios match o linker error and must appear in an Objective-C context

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]How can I solve the problem? I want to throw the project link to friends.
/Users/a/Documents/gpp/gpp/LineKit/Line.h:23:1: '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? the `@end` should definitely be deleted...

Comment: Select the report navigator (Command-8), find the error, expand as much as possible and post the full linker error. Additionally there is an error in the source code.

Comment: https://github.com/dlackty/LineKit where the project smoothly, but to create a new project file named Luna scarce novel project to help attigi few days time error that the visual alıyorum.lütf I'm dealing with it: ((((

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/rQ71nV.png

Comment: The key point from the linker error is :Symbol(s) not found for arm7.

Comment: How do I solve this problem

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/QA90VV.png already it seems to be attached :(